# Maven Eclipse Integration Issue

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, maven, pom.xml

I am having an issue with Maven integration. I have recently downloaded Eclipse Luna (with JDK 8 patch) and using it on Ubuntu OS.

I have created a Maven project with simple artifact and now when I add write some dependency in my pom.xml file and then test it, the Maven build is successful, but in my Java build path, the JRE System Libraries [J2SE-1.5 ] is present but my Maven Dependencies does not contain anything in spite of writing a few dependencies in my POM.xml file.

This is my pom.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>testproject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencyManagement>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
                <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
                <version>5.0.0</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
                <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>

    </dependencyManagement>


</project>
```

Due to my Maven dependencies being not present in my build path, hence, I am not able to use the libraries which are to be added by Maven.

Comment: Install m2e, and use alt-f5 (or maven > update project) to update the maven managed dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to put the dependencies outside of `<dependencyManagement>`

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
            <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

see the [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management) for what `<dependencyManagement>`should be used:

> The dependency management section is a mechanism for centralizing
>   dependency information. When you have a set of projects that inherits
>   a common parent it's possible to put all information about the
>   dependency in the common POM and have simpler references to the
>   artifacts in the child POMs.